# WPF DataGrid with enums in Datatable and AutoGeneratedColummns="True"

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datatable, enums

I have a problem with my enum, datatable and datagrid. I have the following code:

StateEnum.cs:

```
public enum StateEnum
    {
        Pass,
        Fail,
        Mandatory,
        Retest
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.MainViewModel vm = VmSingleton.GetVmInstance();
    vm.ModuleRecords = new System.Data.DataTable();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable("TableName");
    dt.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Operation1", typeof(StateEnum));
    dt.Columns.Add("Operation2", typeof(StateEnum));
    dt.Columns.Add("Operation3", typeof(StateEnum));
    dt.Columns.Add("Operation4", typeof(StateEnum));

    vm.ModuleRecords = dt;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        DataRow newDR = dt.NewRow();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            int j = 1;
            if (col.ColumnName == "Id")
                newDR[col.ColumnName] = i + j;
            else
                newDR[col.ColumnName] = StateEnum.Pass;
            j++;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(newDR);
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
…
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleRecords}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
<Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Ok" Click="Button_Click"/>
…
```

While the Id is shown in the cells, the enums in the cells are not shown directly. When i click on a cell i can choose the right enum. How can i fix it?

Edit:
I´m sorry for the ambiguous description. In my case i want to show the data of a datatable because i dont know exactly how much data has to be shown at design time. That´s why is choose a datatable. In my example i can have more or less operations and i dont know how much there are...

I think i have simplified my problem too much before i post here. This codeexample makes it clearer i hope:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataAccess.DataAccessor accessor = new DataAccess.DataAccessor();

    // i dont know how much operations i got at design time
    List<string> operationHeaders = accessor.getOperationHeaders();

    ViewModel.MainViewModel vm = VmSingleton.GetVmInstance();
    vm.ModuleRecords = new System.Data.DataTable();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable("TableName");
    dt.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int));

    // this is because i have to go through with a for-each 
    // to initialize the header of the table
    foreach (string header in operationHeaders)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(header, typeof(StateEnum));
    }

    vm.ModuleRecords = dt;

    // fil the datatable with data...
    ...
}
```

I hope the situation is clearer now...

Edit 2:
My problem is that the binding of the enum-values doesn´t work properly. I set values in my Viewmodel, but the enum-properties in the datagridview shows only a blank cell. I expected to see the value of the enum-property e.g. "Pass" or "Fail"...
When i click on a cell i see the possible values of the enum, but it is not set directly.

Comment: Please take some time to add some words to your question and try to explain your problem better.

Comment: Nobody? is it the right strategy for that problem? is the problem clear enough? :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: Please see Edit #2 :-)

Comment: I don't know why no one understood your problem as it appeared to me as well: a DataTable that is bound to a WPF DataGrid does not show enum typed values! What part is not clear about that? What is the solution? Did you found one?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use DataTable, use POCOs instead and your life will be a lot easier  while moving to MVVM. The following is a lot more cleaner. 
I have copied the complete Windows code so you can run the demostration without running into troubles but you have to pay attention to the xaml imported namespaces and Window.Resources section:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{

    public enum StateEnum
    {
        Pass,
        Fail,
        Mandatory,
        Retest
    }

    public class ModuleRecord
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public StateEnum Operation1 { get; set; }
        public StateEnum Operation2 { get; set; }
        public StateEnum Operation3 { get; set; }
        public StateEnum Operation4 { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ModuleRecords = new ObservableCollection<ModuleRecord>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ModuleRecord> ModuleRecords { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int j = 1;
                var mRecord = new ModuleRecord();
                mRecord.Id = j;
                mRecord.Operation1 = StateEnum.Pass;
                mRecord.Operation2 = StateEnum.Pass;
                mRecord.Operation3 = StateEnum.Pass;
                mRecord.Operation4 = StateEnum.Pass;
                ModuleRecords.Add(mRecord);

            }
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

... and them the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" 
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EnumDataProvider" 
                        MethodName="GetValues" 
                        ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">

            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:StateEnum"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ModuleRecords}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Header="Id" />
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Operation1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumDataProvider}}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Operation1}"  />
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Operation2" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumDataProvider}}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Operation2}"  />
            </DataGrid.Columns>            

        </DataGrid>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Ok" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I´m sorry, but i recognize that i have to update my answer a bit. (See above) - I have no idea how much operations i have to display in my datagridview at designtime. Thats why i use datatable...